# "in all occasions when" or "in all occasions where"? Or maybe both?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

1) I do so in all occasions when A is the case.

or

2) I do so in all occasions where A is the case.

Or both?

Comment: Both are "correct", and the choice between "where" and "when" is somewhat dependent on context.  "On" is preferred over "in", in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, but "**on** all occasions **when**..." seems to be preferred.

> From [Google Books](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22on+all+occasions%22&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=%22on+all+occasions%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.26351j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22on+all+occasions+when%22):
>
> - "A Companion of the Order of Canada is entitled to (a) have the letters 'C.C.' placed after his name **on all occasions when** use of such letters is customary"
> - "We are also bound to speak the truth to an enemy **on all occasions when** we are naturally obliged to it by the laws of humanity"
> - "Bogart testified that **on all occasions when** employees asked him to use the copy machine for personal reasons, he denied their requests."

EDIT - In case anyone missed the bold letters at the top, we say "**on** all occasions". That's the right preposition here.

Comment: Centaurus, please; are you suggesting that a person or a thing can be "in" an occasion?

Could you give an example, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin  ON all occasions.   Please, read again.  I never wrote "in".

Comment: No, you didn't use the word "in", and that's the point.

You did write 'Both are correct, but "on all occasions when..." seems to be preferred.'

D'you not think that apart from anything else, most readers would infer from that there was nothing really wrong with "in all occasions…"; it's just used less often?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin   True, I didn't say it clearly that "in" was the wrong preposition to use.  In case you missed it, however, I typed "on" with bold letters.  That should be enough for the OP to understand that they had used the wrong preposition.

Comment: …so he might, with "might" being the operative word.

Still, Merry Christmas!